# How to write a stored procedure with a parameter which ignores upper or lower case sensitive

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, sql-like

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this one?

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[UrunuGetir](@basharf nvarchar(5))
as
     select adi, urunid, kategori 
     from urun 
     where (UPPER(adi) like UPPER('%' +'@basharf'+ '%')) 
           or (LOWER(adi) like LOWER ('%' +'@basharf'+ '%')) 
     order by kategori
```

No errors but also no data.

Here is the edit:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (TextBox1.Text != null) 
   { 
      UrunGetir(TextBox1.Text); 
   } 
   else 
   { 
     return; 
   } 
} 

private void UrunGetir(string p)
{
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("....");

    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select adi, urunid, kategori, birimf from urun where (UPPER(adi) like '%' + UPPER(@basharf) + '%' ) or (LOWER(adi) like '%' + LOWER(@basharf) + '%' ) order by kategori", baglanti);

    dap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@basharf", p);

    if (baglanti.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        baglanti.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dap.Fill(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    if (baglanti.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        baglanti.Close();

    HiddenField1.Value = p.Substring(0,p.Length);
}
```

Comment: You don't need both LOWER() and UPPER() in your WHERE clause.   Just a note, the answers below explain why you are not getting results

Comment: How can I ignore sql upper lower case sensitivity than?

Comment: By using one or the other, you don't need both. If you use `UPPER(adi)`, the result will be upper case. Then using `UPPER` on your argument makes it upper case also. Everything is now upper case and there's no need to worry about lower case. The same logic applies if you choose to lower case everything.

Comment: I did it as you mentioned: ALTER proc [dbo].[UrunuGetir](@basharf nvarchar(5))
as
select adi, urunid, kategori, birimf from urun where (UPPER(adi) like '%' + @basharf + '%') order by kategori    And also updated parameter UPPER() from server side but still no data

Comment: This would work better: `ALTER proc [dbo].[UrunuGetir](@basharf nvarchar(5)) as select adi, urunid, kategori, birimf from urun where (UPPER(adi) like '%' + UPPER(@basharf) + '%')`

Answer (score 3):

This bit:

```
UPPER('%' +'@basharf'+ '%')
```

You are concatenating three strings, so this expression is equal to:

```
UPPER('%@basharf%')
```

You probably mean:

```
'%' + UPPER(@basharf) + '%'
```

Which concatenates the passed in parameter with the `%` signs.

Comment: Thanks Oded, but amazingly, your correction returns data when I search for "cha" but not for "chai" I dont know why, but in db it is written like "CHAI"

Comment: I suspect the last letter in CHAI is not actually an I, but rather a lower-case 'l'.   Try searching for CHAL and see what comes back

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a DBMS handy to check this, but I think you'll want to put the `%` outside of the `UPPER` and `LOWER` functions.

Like so:

```
'%' + UPPER(@basharf) + '%'
```

---

Update

Googling `SqlDataAdapter` makes me think you're using C#. I'm not familiar with that database API, so I can't offer any help there. However, as a general troubleshooting tip, I would recommend getting the query correct against the database alone before trying to run it from within your GUI code.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but amazingly, your correction returns data when I search for "cha" but not for "chai" I dont know why, but in db it is written like "CHAI"

Comment: We'd need to see more to help with that. Post some data and an example of how you're calling your procedure.

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (TextBox1.Text != null) { UrunGetir(TextBox1.Text); } else { return; } }

Comment: I'm confused. That looks like Java, not a stored procedure call.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you people who answered my question but I guess I found the solution...

```
string kelime = TextBox1.Text;
        char[] oldValue = new char[] { 'i' };
        char[] newValue = new char[] { 'I' };
        for (int sayac = 0; sayac < oldValue.Length; sayac++)
        {
            kelime = kelime.Replace(oldValue[sayac], newValue[sayac]).ToLower();
        }
```

Than, as you mentioned :

```
SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select adi, birimf, kategori, urunid from urun where (UPPER(adi) like '%' + UPPER(@basharf) + '%') order by kategori", baglanti);
        dap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@basharf", kelime);
```